# Generating new rows based on size of family to size N

Tags: python

in this problem I want to use any library in python to help me out

we have a variable N

for sake of example lets assume N=3  (i want N to be dynamic so if I change it the out put changes)

input is an array with two columns for sake of example

```
Depth   SBL
1100    10
1300    10
1450    8
1650    8
1770    8
1863    5
1900    5
1956    4
2012    3
2068    2
2124    1
2180    1
2236    1
2292    1
2348    1
```

then we create new row that shows how many times is SBL is repeated

```
df['family_size'] = df.SBL.map(df.SBL.value_counts())
```

out put is

```
    Depth   SBL family_size
0   1100    10  2
1   1300    10  2
2   1450    8   3
3   1650    8   3
4   1770    8   3
5   1863    5   2
6   1900    5   2
7   1956    4   1
8   2012    3   1
9   2068    2   1
10  2124    1   5
11  2180    1   5
12  2236    1   5
13  2292    1   5
14  2348    1   5
```

then what im struggling with is

re sampling based on N
which for the sake of example is 3

i want python to manipulate "interpolate" (creates new data or removes actual data and puts in new data to down-sample to size N=3) in other word force family_size to be N=3

and changes Depth accordingly . and if possible appends new column with value 1,2,3 repeated for every SBL

like the following output

```
Depth   SBL POSTION
1100    10  1
1200    10  2
1300    10  3
1450    8   1
1650    8   2
1770    8   3
1863    5   1
1881.5  5   2
1900    5   3
1928    4   1
1956    4   2
1984    4   3
…etc    …etc    1
…etc    …etc    2
…etc    …etc    3
```

Comment: You are using `panda`, right? Also you should show your code and sample data (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can use any library . I just need to do this I cant figure out a way plz help :((

Comment: It wouldn't take much logic to iterate over your first set of output and build a list containing the min and max values for each SBL.  Then you would just iterate for each of the SBLs, and for each one, write out 3 lines/rows that reproduce your second output.  This is a pretty basic programming problem, if you know Python at all.

Comment: ...btw, wouldn't your depths for SBL 4 be 1956, 1956, 1956?

Comment: yes but im a beginner